# Maths using javascript and multiple html fields

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, sum

I have a script that dynamically creates a table with a varying number of columns and rows based on a db query.
This is done twice, on two different db tables.
I have a row at the bottom of each table with an input whose value is the sum of the cells in the column above.
These inputs are named `itotal$m` (where `$m` is an incrementing number) for the first table and `etotal$m` for the second table. So what I end up with is a number of input fields with the names `itotal1`, `itotal2` etc for the first row of totals and `etotal1`, `etotal2` etc for the second row.

I want to perform some simple maths with these totals, subtracting `etotal1` from `itotal1`, `etotal2` from `itotal2` and so on, then displaying the result in another input.
I would like to use javascript function attached to an `onChange` event so that the user can change the input box values and see the result.

Unfortunately, I have not managed to figure out how to do this.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you post your HTML?  Or better yet, create a JSFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming :

- the two tables to have `id="iTable"` and `id="eTable"`,
- all the column total fields to have `class="colTotal"`,
- the two tables to be congruous (ie. their columns are in the same order),
- the target input elements to have `class="diffValue"`, then :

jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    var $iTableTotals = $("#iTable .colTotal");
    var $eTableTotals = $("#eTable .colTotal");
    var $diffValues = $(".diffValue");
    $(".colTotal").on('change keyup', function() {
        $iTableTotals.each(function(i){
            var diff = Number($iTableTotals.eq(i).val()) - Number($eTableTotals.eq(i).val());
            $diffValues.eq(i).val(diff);
        });
    });
    $iTableTotals.eq(0).change();
});
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yHFwH/)